# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Home#home No route me atches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actioncontroller

I get the error:

```
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Home#home  No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

in my home controller. When I am sign in, I get errors in the home/home mostly about

```
No route matches...:controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id].
```

For some reason, it looks like the sign_in is not working or the current_user is nil .

Any idea on how to solve this error ? I am using devise and omniauth.

Here is my users_model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX = 'change@me'
TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX = /\Achange@me/
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :lockable, :timeoutable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable
validates_format_of :email, :without => TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX, on: :update
def self.find_for_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)
# Get the identity and user if they exist
 identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)
# If a signed_in_resource is provided it always overrides the existing    user
# to prevent the identity being locked with accidentally created accounts.
# Note that this may leave zombie accounts (with no associated identity)  which
# can be cleaned up at a later date.
user = signed_in_resource ? signed_in_resource : identity.user

# Create the user if needed
 if user.nil?

 # Get the existing user by email if the provider gives us a verified email.
 # If no verified email was provided we assign a temporary email and ask the
 # user to verify it on the next step via UsersController.finish_signup
 email_is_verified = auth.info.email && (auth.info.verified || auth.info.verified_email)
 email = auth.info.email if email_is_verified
 user = User.where(:email => email).first if email

# Create the user if it's a new registration
if user.nil?
user = User.new(
  name: auth.extra.raw_info.name,
  #username: auth.info.nickname || auth.uid,
  email: email ? email : "#{TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX}-#{auth.uid}-#{auth.provider}.com",
  password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
)
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save!
  end
  end

 # Associate the identity with the user if needed
  if identity.user != user
  identity.user = user
  identity.save!
  end
 user
end

def email_verified?
self.email && self.email !~ TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX
end
end
```

Here is my shared/user_info.html.erb:

```
<h1><%= current_user.email %></h1>
<span><%= link_to "view my profile", current_user %></span>
<span><%= pluralize(current_user.posts.count, "post") %></span>
<%end%>
```

Here is my app/views/layouts/header.html.erb:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<div class="container">
<%= link_to "UNSTARV ALPHA", '#', id: "logo" %>
<nav>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><%= link_to "Home",   root_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Groups",   groups_path %></li>
  <% if signed_in? %>
      <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Account <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
            <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Sign up", signup_path %></li>
        <% end %>

         </div></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
           </div>
```

Here is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'groups/new'

  get 'groups/create'

  get 'groups/show'

  get 'groups/edit'

  get 'groups/update'

  get 'groups/destroy'
  get 'groups' => 'groups#index'
  get 'groups/new'
  get 'signup' =>'users#new'
  get 'rooms'  =>'home#rooms'

  match '/users/:id/finish_signup' => 'users#finish_signup', via: [:get, :patch], :as => :finish_signup


  devise_for :users, :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }

  resources :users do
  member do
  get :following, :followers
  end
  end


  root 'home#home' 
  get 'terms' => 'home#terms'
  get 'privacy' => 'home#privacy'
  get 'about' => 'home#about'

  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :posts  do
  member { post :vote }
  resources :comments do
  member { post :vote }
  end
  end

  resources :groups
  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Here is my full trace:

```
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:219:in `raise_generation_error'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:192:in `optimized_helper'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:178:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:270:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:20:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__4827727_36507960'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8)lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__798221577_35492700'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:67:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8)lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord
(4.1.8)lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 activesupport (4.1.8)      lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
 actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
 railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
 railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Here is my omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def self.provides_callback_for(provider)
class_eval %Q{
  def #{provider}
    @user = User.find_for_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "#{provider}".capitalize)    if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
  }
 end

[:twitter, :facebook, :linked_in].each do |provider|
provides_callback_for provider
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
#if resource.email_verified?
  super resource
  current_user = @user
#else
 # finish_signup_path(resource)
 #end
 end
end
```

And my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :finish_signup]

def index
@users = User.all
end 

# GET /users/:id.:format
def show
# authorize! :read, @user

 end

# GET /users/:id/edit
def edit
# authorize! :update, @user
end
def new
@user = User.new
end

# PATCH/PUT /users/:id.:format
def update
# authorize! :update, @user
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update(user_params)
    sign_in(@user == current_user ? @user : current_user, :bypass => true)
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
  end

  # GET/PATCH /users/:id/finish_signup
  def finish_signup
  # authorize! :update, @user 
  if request.patch? && params[:user] #&& params[:user][:email]
  if @user.update(user_params)
    @user.skip_reconfirmation!
    sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
    redirect_to @user, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.'
  else
    @show_errors = true
  end
  end
  end

  # DELETE /users/:id.:format
  def destroy
  # authorize! :delete, @user
  @user.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to root_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  end
  end
  def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def following
   @title = "Following"
   @user  = User.find(params[:id])
   @users = @user.following.paginate(page: params[:page])
   render 'show_follow'
   end

   def followers
   @title = "Followers"
   @user  = User.find(params[:id])
   @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
   render 'show_follow'
   end



  private
  def user_params
  accessible = [ :name, :email ] # extend with your own params
  accessible << [ :password, :password_confirmation ] unless params[:user][:password].blank?
  params.require(:user).permit(:database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:confirmable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,   :omniauthable,:encrypted_password, #:confirmed_at)
 end
 end
```

Comment: Show us your config.routes.rb file or run `rake routes` . Show where and/or how are you calling this action. My best guess is that you are calling this action with out passing a user id. Something like this `<%= link_to  "Edit account", edit_user_path(@user), class: 'btn btn-success' %>` In you code you might be missing @user.

Comment: show `app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb` line 20.

Comment: @LuisMenjivar I added more info

Comment: the error is all about missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: @AbM , this error happens only after I sign_in or sign_up. Before I do so, there is no error, but if I am signed in the current_user is nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too familiar with Omniauth to be honest, and I don't know if this is the right answer but here are my 2 cents.

I am thinking maybe your `<li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>` is not getting the id from `current_user`. Try deleting that line to see if the error goes away. 
Maybe when a user signs in using omniauth, it does NOT create the user and it only creates a user once the user verifies his email, or it only creates a user if the email is valid in Facebook/Twitter/whatnot. So when you call on current_user, current_user does not exists.

Sign in using omniauth using a valid (facebook/twitter/whatnot) email, then check your database to see if it created a user.

Try `<li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(@user) %></li>`
or try `<li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(@user.id) %></li>` That might work. I hope this helps.

Comment: Before I sign_in or sign_up I don t get the error. It's only after I sign in or sign up, then current_user is a nilClass.